# Возврат указателя на функцию

Tags: c++

Каким образом можно вернуть указатель на функцию из функции?

```
void f0(char) {}

void (*)(char) f1() {return f0;} // В возвращаемом типе ошибка
```

Можно объявить `auto` возвращаемым типом, но так не интересно!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нашел [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912179/error-in-return-a-function-pointer-in-c-without-typedef/17912231#17912231) на англоязычном SO.

В вашем случае правильное определение для f1 будет:

```
void (*f1())(char) { return f0; }
```

В общем случае сигнатура должна быть такая:

```
возвращаемое_значение_возвращаемой_функции (*имя_функции(типы_параметров_функции))(типы_параметров_возвращаемой_функции);
```

Вообще, не рекомендую использовать такой синтаксис, т.к. сигнатура получается нечитаемой. Лучше создать аллиас на возвращаемый тип с помощью `using` или `typedef`:

```
using Function = void (*)(char);

Function f1() {
  return f0;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Чтобы вернуть указатель на функцию, можно использовать следующие способы.

1) Явное указание типа.

```
void (*f1())(char) { return f0; }
```

2) Объявление синонима типа через `typedef`.

```
typedef void (*TFunc)(char);
TFunc f1() { return f0; }
```

3) Объявление синонима типа через `using` (`c++11`).

```
using TFunc = void (*)(char);
TFunc f1() { return f0; }
```

4) Полуавтоматическое определение возвращаемого типа (`c++11`).

```
auto f1() -> decltype(&f0) { return f0; }
```

5) Автоматическое определение возвращаемого типа (`c++14`).

```
auto f1() { return f0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы не запутаться в синтаксисе, вы можете просто объявить с помощью `typedef` имя типа. который собираетесь вернуть из функции.

Например,

```
typedef void ( *pf )( char );
```

И затем записываете

```
void f0( char ) {}

pf f1() { return f0; }
```

Без использование `typedef` определение функции будет выглядеть более запутанным:

```
void f0( char ) {}
void ( *( f1() ) )( char ) { return f0; }
```

Вот демонстрационные программы, которые показывают оба подхода

```
#include <iostream>

void f0( char c ) { std::cout << "char: " << c << std::endl; }

typedef void ( *pf )( char );

pf f1() { return f0; }    

int main()
{
    f1()( 'A' );

    return 0;
}

#include <iostream>

void f0( char c ) { std::cout << "char: " << c << std::endl; }
void ( *( f1() ) )( char ) { return f0; }

int main()
{
    f1()( 'A' );

    return 0;
}
```

В обоиъ случаях вывод на консоль будет:

```
char: A
```